# Symfony2 remember me without form

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.3

In our application we have got an AJAX registration/authentication based on the FOSUserBundle. Now we want to set the remember me cookie by default. The problem is that the remember me services of symfony2 are not public so it's not possible to access them. Does somebody have a clue how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer was to create an alias for the remember me services to make them public.

```
<service id="custom.security.service.remember_me" alias="security.authentication.rememberme.services.simplehash.main"/>
```